# Is Σ* the same as saying L*

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm getting confused over the two. Are they the same? The complement of a language L is Σ* - L. Is saying L* - L wrong?

Comment: Let $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, $L=\{0\}$. Then $L^* = \{ 0^k\}_k \neq \Sigma^*$.

Comment: Usually, $\Sigma$ refers to the alphabet that you're working over, and $\ast$ means "all finite strings over". In other words, $\Sigma^\ast$ is the set of all strings in your universe. On the other hand, $L^\ast$ has a very different meaning: all strings that can be made by concatenating words in $L$.

Comment: Is L* = $L^0$ U $L^1$ U ... $L^n$ or is it the concatenation of them?

Answer (score 3):

By definition, $L^* = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} L^n$. Also, $\Sigma$ is the language of all words of length $1$ (equivalently, $\Sigma$ is the alphabet). So $\Sigma^* = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} \Sigma^n$. There is no particular reason to assume that $\Sigma^* = L^*$. For example, suppose that $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ while $L = \{a\}$. Then $\Sigma^*$ consists of all words over $a,b$, while $L^*$ consists of all words over $a$.

In fact, it is not hard to show that $L^* = \Sigma^*$ iff $\Sigma \subseteq L$ (exercise).